# HTML5 Player not Auto Playing Video

Tags: html, wordpress, autoplay

I am trying Run Video on my site but its not getting auto play, can someone check and tell what could be a reason.

I am using Plugin called Video.js of wordpress and here is the code i am using

```
[videojs mp4="http://nostradamus.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/mg.mp4" width="258" height="145" autoplay="true" loop="true" controls="false"]
```

Video is loading fine but not playing auto, when you right click on video and click play then its play even i used the

```
autoplay="true" , autoplay , autoplay="on"
```

All three not works, however loop works, control tag work, just no auto play. Tried it playing in chrome and firefox latest no luck on both.

Here is url to site

```
http://nostradamus.fr
```

Click on the slider button

```
CLIQUEZ ICI
```

You will see girl holding phone, it is video. So please help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's in a modal and seems to be loaded along with the rest of the page, you may not want to have it autoplay anyways. This may cause the video to play without it even being present on the page. Not sure if this is entirely true though.

I would suggest just having a jQuery function activate on click on the button that would start playing the video.

Comment: can you tell that jquery function